# mobile application using intellij

Tags: android, jquery, sqlite, cordova, intellij-idea

I created mobile application using intellij,jquery and for the database i use sqlite, in the browser emulator the application works good but when convert it into apk and install to android smartphone i cant save my inputs to my database need help with this thankyou in advance
this is my config.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
```

helloworld
    
        Hello World sample application that responds to the deviceready event.
    
    
        PhoneGap Team

this is my db

```
var dbHandler = {
db: null,
createDatabase: function () {
    this.db = window.openDatabase("abc","1.0","Learning Process",1000000);

    this.db.transaction(
        function (tx) {
            // run sql using tx
            tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE  if not EXISTS student(student_id integer PRIMARY KEY autoincrement,name text,password text, school text)"
                ,[],function (tx,results){},function (tx,error) {console.log("Transaction Error: " + error.message);}
            );
            tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE  if not EXISTS subject(subject_id integer PRIMARY KEY autoincrement,subject_name text,student_id integer, foreign key (student_id) references student(student_id) )"
                ,[],function (tx,results){},function (tx,error) {console.log("Transaction Error: " + error.message);}
            );
            tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE if not EXISTS assesments(assesment_id integer PRIMARY KEY autoincrement,description text,quizzes float,item float,date date,assignments float, exam float,projects float, subject_id integer,remarks varchar(10),student_id int, foreign key (subject_id) references subject(subject_id))",
                [],function (tx,results){},function (tx,error) {console.log("Transaction Error: " + error.message);}
                );
        },
        function (error) {},
        function () {
            console.log("Create database transaction successfully");
        }


    );
}
```

}

Comment: what is log? can you share it ?

Comment: it is only for prompting if the database is successfully created.

Answer (score 0):

Can implement this way

1. onclick event from js pass those values as Json to Cordova activty
2. create custom plugin
3. in onExecute method of your custom plugin pass json obj as param and do callback

Comment: is there's any other way using jquery mobile?`